Compile and run Rust program on save in VS Code?
I've just installed the rust-analyzer VS Code extension and configured "format on save" using rustfmt. Hitting the "Run" button also works nicely. However, in order to speed up my workflow, I'd like to automatically have "cargo run" on save.
I've seen that there's cargo watch that seems to do the job, but I've also read that it might collide with rust-analyzer. Some even seem to use nodemon. Which makes me wonder: isn't there an official way to run Rust programs on save from within VS Code? How do you optimize your workflow?
https://users.rust-lang.org/t/vscode-rust-analyzer-and-cargo-watch-x-run-recompile-when-saving/85671

cargo watch is excellent. If it collides with rust-analyzer, there are solutions to that.

You could also use Run on Save, but I doubt, that there is built-in support for this feature.

You may be able to just set the rust-analyzer.check.command setting to run (by default it is check). If that doesn't work, you could set it to build and do cargo watch -s target/debug/<executable> instead.

I would try simply using cargo watch -x run with the default rust-analyzer settings first, though.

@PitaJ thanks, both of your approaches cargo watch -x and cargo watch -s … (with command set to build) seem to work fine! Setting the command to run fails with error: unexpected argument '--workspace' found; tip: to pass '--workspace' as a value, use '-- --workspace', but for now I can live with the other approaches. Thanks again, feel free to make this the official answer!

Another way is to set rust-analyzer.check.command to build and simply have the binary watched and executed using fswatch -o target/debug/<executable> | xargs -n1 -I{} ./target/debug/<executable>.

If cargo run conflicts with rust analyzer, you can set rust analyzer to use a build dir separate from target so that they don't compete for the lock on the build directory. Setting Rust-analyzer › Cargo: Target Dir (rust-analyzer.cargo.targetDir)
